# react-toastify: How to position the toasts a little up from the bottom

Tags: react-toastify

I want to position the toast at the `bottom-right` but with some offset from the bottom

example,.

[image]

Currently this is my `ToastContainer` definition

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hist}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
      <Redirect from="/" to="/admin" />
    </Switch>
    <ToastContainer
        position="bottom-right"
        autoClose={500000}
        hideProgressBar
        newestOnTop={false}
        closeOnClick
        rtl={false}
        pauseOnFocusLoss
        draggable
        pauseOnHover
    />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I checked the css it shows

```
.Toastify__toast-container--bottom-right {
    bottom: 1em;
    right: 1em;
}
```

HOw to adjust this to

```
.Toastify__toast-container--bottom-right {
    bottom: 11em;
    right: 1.5em;
}
```

Where can i mention this

Answer (score 2):

Just mention it in the CSS imported in your .jsx file.
Please add a `className` to your Container like

```
<ToastContainer
        className="toast-position"
        position="top-center"
        autoClose={10000}
        hideProgressBar={false}
        newestOnTop={false}
        closeOnClick
        rtl={false}
        pauseOnFocusLoss
        draggable
        pauseOnHover
        theme="dark"
      />
```

And then in your css file you can do something like this

```
.toast-position {
  top: 8rem !important;
}
```

You can also checkout here for more info
https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify/issues/263

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).